# SameSite error in my Django + React authentication app

Tags: reactjs, django, cookies, django-rest-framework, samesite

## SameSite error in my Django + React authentication app

[Here's the image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2ZSQ.png)

I have a simple React + Django authentication app I deployed just for testing. I'm using Django Rest Framework. However, I'm facing this error when I click 'Login'. Basically, because of this error, the server isn't able to send/set cookies to the client.

Here's the Django view:

```
class Login(APIView):
 def post(self, request):
        email = request.data['email']
        password = request.data['password']

        user = User.objects.filter(email=email).first()

        if user is None:
         raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('Invalid credentials')
        
        if not user.check_password(password):
         raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('Invalid credentials')
        
        refresh_token = create_refresh_token(user.id)
        access_token = create_access_token(user.id)

        UserToken.objects.create(
         user_id=user.id,
         token=refresh_token,
         expired_at=datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(days=365)
        )

        response = Response()

        response.set_cookie(key='refresh_token', value=refresh_token, httponly=True)
        response.set_cookie(key='access_token', value=access_token, httponly=True)
        response.data = UserSerializer(user).data
        return response
```

In short, when I send '/login/' POST request to the server, it uses set_cookie() to set cookies on the client side. It works fine in the dev environment but gets messed up in the production environment.

Client Github Code: https://github.com/MrGuardianGo/React-Django-Authentication-Client

Server Github Code: https://github.com/MrGuardianGo/React-Django-Authentication-Server

Help will be really appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide more details on the error displayed ? Sounds like a problem with CORS

Comment: Sure. I've added the image of the error.

Comment: Thanks for the error. I've answered below. And just as a friendly reminder, on Stackoverflow you should not post error as image as explained in this [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: I'll definitely keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

To correct the same site error in Django and React, you have to configure the cookie for CROSS DOMAIN and CORS if the front and the back are on different sub-domain for example: [www.onrender.com](http://www.onrender.com), my-frontend.onrender.com and my-backend.onrender.com

### Configure cookie in settings

In settings.py set the following:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '.onrender.com'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'
```

[SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#session-cookie-domain) allows different possible domains: [www.onrender.com](http://www.onrender.com), api.onrender.com and my-backend.onrender.com

### Configure CORS

You can use django-cors-headers for managing the CORS

**1** Install [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers)

```
pip install django-cors-headers
```

**2** In the settings.py:

2.1 Add "corsheaders" to installed apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    "corsheaders",
    ...,
]
```

2.2 Add "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware" to middleware:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...,
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    ...,
]
```

2.3 Configure the allowed origins:

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "https://www.onrender.com",
    "https://django-auth-server.onrender.com",
    "https://my-frontend.onrender.com",
    "http://my-frontend.onrender.com",
    ...
]
```

**OR** you can configure a REGEX

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGIN_REGEXES = [
    r"^https://\w+\.onrender\.com$",
    r"^http://\w+\.onrender\.com$",
]
```

Some more [information about origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin), a same origin is based on **"scheme (protocol), hostname (domain), and port"** ([protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Web_mechanics/What_is_a_URL#scheme)://[domain:port](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Web_mechanics/What_is_a_URL#authority)). Following this rule, these URLs are different:

- http://example.com
- https://example.com
- https://example.com:8000
- http://www.example.com
- http://myapp.example.com

More documentations:

- [SameSite values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#samesitesamesite-value)
- [Cross-Origin Site Request (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)
- [What's an URL (Mozilla)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Web_mechanics/What_is_a_URL#basics_anatomy_of_a_url)

Comment: I'm still getting the error. The only thing I did differently from what you said was instead of CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGIN_REGEXES and CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS, I just put CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True. Could this be a problem?

Comment: "CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True" should be fine. Is your client side correctly call the server ? And have you the detailed request and response (it could give yo'u some more hint to correct the error)

Comment: Yeah, I've called the server from the client side correctly. And I even checked in the console and found no error apart from SameSite.